# Debugging Magento

Tags: debugging, magento, header

Any ideas what this means?

`2011-10-20T11:30:47+00:00 DEBUG (7): HEADERS ALREADY SENT: <pre>[0] /chroot/home/.../html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:44
[1] /chroot/home/..../html/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php:766
[2] /chroot/home/..../html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:75
[3] /chroot/home/.../html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php:188
[4] /chroot/home/.../html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:340
[5] /chroot/home/.../html/app/Mage.php:627
[6] /chroot/home/.../html/index.php:80`

thanks for your time!

Comment: Welcome to SO! "Headers already sent" is a fairly common problem in PHP and has been seen many times on SO already - check out the available answers, one of them might help

Answer (score 2):

It means you're producing output in Magento prior to the system's response object's automatic  output being created.

Magento uses a response object to control all output sent.  Once a controller's been dispatched, Magento tells the response object to send its headers, and then send its output.  This means if you produce output **anywhere** that's not a part of the layout system, when the response object gets to sending it's headers it will detect that output has already been sent to the browser, and will spew the above warning to the logs.

Comment: Thank you Alan, is it something to be concerned of? How would you recommend debugging the issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find any solutions for this just put `ob_start()` in your top of the file it removes all headrs and start new header this will surely solve your problem